# Spotify - How/Where to generate ENCRYPTION_SECRET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to implement this plugin https://github.com/Festify/cordova-spotify-oauth

https://github.com/Festify/cordova-spotify-oauth/blob/develop/oauth-token-api/spotifyTokenService.js

```
CLIENT_ID="got from spotify dev account"
CLIENT_SECRET="got from spotify dev account"
CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL="my-app://callback"
ENCRYPTION_SECRET="<Secret used to encrypt the refresh token - please generate>"
```

In above env variables whatever I put in **ENCRYPTION_SECRET** it always throws error as

```
TypeError: Bad input string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Decipher.update (crypto.js:146:26)
    at Object.module.exports.decrypt (/user_code/lib/crypto.js:14:21)
    at exports.refreshToken.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:104:31)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:37:41)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:689:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:673:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I have tried:

- ENCRYPTION_SECRET=123
- ENCRYPTION_SECRET=cFJLyifeUJUBFWdHzVbykfDmPHtLKLGzViHW9aHGmyTLD8hGXC *(just a random text)*
- Also searched in Spotify Dev Account, did not find any option to generate ENCRYPTION_SECRET

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it a typo in your question ?  `ENCRYPTION_SECRECT` should be `ENCRYPTION_SECRET`

Comment: As per docs it's **ENCRYPTION_SECRET** and in my code also it's **ENCRYPTION_SECRET**

Comment: It's just a random string used to encrypt your keys. Did you wrap it in quotes in your .env file?

Comment: Not wrapped in quotes

Comment: @AlexMan So, you should edit your question and remove the typo in the examples you've put in it. ;o)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Updated the question with ENCRYPTION_SECRET everywhere

Comment: @AlexMan You should take a look to this link : https://github.com/rorygilchrist/node-spotify-token-swap . In this file (https://github.com/rorygilchrist/node-spotify-token-swap/blob/fe5da9be92fa925475cc8692b6883cc512c75d15/encryption.js) at line 3, you should find what you need. It seems taht he generate a random string with a length of 30.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption key can be whatever you want, it’s simply a key to make sure the communication of the refresh token is secure.